# LESS.app like application?

Tags: software-recommendation, css

Recently I found out about an OS X application called [LESS.app](http://incident57.com/less/). It’s basically an app to compile and minify *.less files into *.css files and does it in real-time. I want to know or I can archive the same thing in Ubuntu and how to go about it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Bryan here. Developer of Less.app.

I highly recommend AGAINST using the older version of LESS (the Ruby-based one). Less.js isn't just a javascript port of LESS, it's a ground-up rewrite that improves a ton of stuff, adds support for things that the old Ruby version doesn't have, and increases compiler speed by about 84%.

Rather than install the Ruby gem, [install Node.js](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installation) and run [Less.js](http://lesscss.org/#guide) through Node from the command line. You'll still have all the -watch functionality, but you'll be using Less.js to do it, which means your life will be much better.

Alternately, use Less.js as a script in the website you're creating. This will work for development. When you're done coding, simply copy the CSS that Less.js generates (from your browser's inspector) and place that into a file, add a .css extension, then remove the Less.js script tag from the HTML pages and substitute the CSS file you just created.

Either way, use Less.js.

Comment: Thanks Bryan, I was not aware of a Less.js compiler other than the one that has to be injected in the page –I suppose a port of Less.app for Ubuntu is out of the question. ;)

Comment: http://fadeyev.net/2010/06/19/lessjs-will-obsolete-css/

Comment: Does less.js work on headless build machines?  I'm getting a "ReferenceError: window is not defined" when I try to run it.

Comment: Note that the ruby version of less now runs off of less.js

Answer (score 3):

> **Note**
>
> Read Bryan's answer. He knows what he's talking about. ;-)

You can just install [less](http://lesscss.org/).

1. Install rubygems and less

   ```
   sudo apt-get install rubygems
   sudo gem install less
   ```
2. The official [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RubyOnRails) remarks:

   > To make gem work properly you should write gem's path to PATH add to ~/.bashrc:
   >
   > ```
   >  export PATH=/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin:$PATH
   > ```
3. You can then use the less compiler by doing

   ```
   lessc style.less
   ```

I don't think there's a GUI like the one you've linked to. But since it only seems to be a very shallow gui on top  of the real less compiler, I don't think you'll have any problems using it directly. Type

```
lessc --help
```

to learn how to use it.

If you want your .less files to be automatically compiled every time you change them, you can use the `-w` option:

```
~$ lessc test.less -w
* Watching for changes in test.less... Ctrl-C to abort.
: Change detected... * Updated test.css
: Change detected... * Updated test.css
```

You can put this process in the background by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and typing `bg`, and start as many as you like. You can bring them back to the foreground by doing `fg`, or `fg 3` for the third process, to get a list of all of the jobs and their numbers type `jobs`.

Comment: Thank you! Right now I use Less.js (http://bit.ly/9bG1E9) but I’ll give the ruby compiler a try. The GUI isn’t important to me. But what I really like to have is a tool that watch my .less file(s) and compile a .css every time I save changes to my .less file. How it is done, through an app, CLI or an gedit plug-in doesn’t matter to me much.

Comment: @Mood, it does that - I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: Wow! Thanks again. That’s exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, ruby less isn't updated enough to even handle the concatenation operator.

For those interested in a solution that compiles .less upon save for non mac platforms using less.js, you can check out [this installation guide](http://www.vertstudios.com/blog/less-app-windows-sorta/)*. Though the tutorial is geared towards Windows users, I imagine if you can [get Node.js](http://www.codediesel.com/linux/installing-node-js-on-ubuntu-10-04/) on your system, the script itself will function the same.

*Disclaimer: This tutorial is mine. Just thought people might want to see specifically what the poster above meant by "Use Node.js". I wasn't able to find any scripts online for using Node.js to compile LESS upon file save, so I cooked one up and thought I would share it.

Comment: It's great to have your participation, but this looks odd -- advertising a post on your own site for a Windows solution?  Does this add something that the other answers don't?

Comment: Yes - non ruby, non MacOSX. You can use the less.js script that works with node.js, so non MacOSX users that can get Node.js compiled can enjoy instant .less compilation.

Comment: Getting Node.js running is not hard. Not sure or I followed this article http://www.codediesel.com/linux/installing-node-js-on-ubuntu-10-04/ but Node.js was set up in no time. Setting up Less.js however had me pulling out some hairs. I figure once you have Node.js running on Ubuntu you can follow the steps in Joseph’s tutorial to get less.js up and running and thus this is a helpful addition to this thread.

Answer (score 2):

Under Ubuntu 11.10, you can simply issue a

```
sudo apt-get install lessc
```

Answer (score 1):

you can install it the command line compiler in Ubuntu 12.10 as well:

```
sudo apt-get install node-less
```

Answer (score 0):

There's also http://koala-app.com/.

http://crunchapp.net/ was my favorite, but we have to thank Adobe for discontinuing AIR for Linux.